# What does get_string() return?

Tags: c, string, cs50

```
string s= get_string("s: ") ;
printf("%s\n", s) ;
```

Look at the code above. Normally get_string should return the address of the string entered which is a number. But when you actually try to printout s, the entered string is printed out. Why is the address ie number not printed out?

Comment: [This](https://man.cs50.io/3/get_string) may help you..

Comment: From where function `get_string` came from?

Answer (score 1):

**Behavior of [get_string](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.c/):**

It prompts user for a line of text from `stdin` and [returns](https://man.cs50.io/3/get_string) it as a string.

So it will give you pointer to a (the first character of) C-style string and a `printf` with a format specifier of `%s` prints out the characters until it hits a null terminating character.

**Getting Pointer Value:**

To print the pointer with `printf`, you have to use the correct format specifier. A `printf` with `%s` will print the value. To get the pointer, you should use a format specifier `%p`.